# Dart/Polymer: Events firing before my app's constructor runs, before event listeners registered

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

Here is my `index.html`:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

    <title>My App</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css" shim-shadowdom>

    <link rel="import" href="packages/myapp_frontend/elements/my_app/my_app.html">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="packages/myapp_frontend/fonts/fonts.css">

    <script src="cordova.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
  </head>

  <body unresolved fullbleed>
    <my-app></my-app>

    <script src="socket.io.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
    <script src="main.dart" type="application/dart"></script>
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Inside `my_app.html` lists all the elements for the entire app.  This is fine.  Some of the elements are plugin wrappers, such as `<cordova-app-version on-app-version="{{ onVersionInfo }}"></cordova-app-version>` that wraps `cordova_app_version_plugin`.  This element looks like this:

```
@CustomTag('cordova-app-version')
class CordovaAppVersion extends PolymerElement {
  CordovaAppVersion.created() : super.created() {
    document.on['deviceready'].listen((var e) {
      this.fire('app-version', detail: 
            context['cordova']['plugins']['version'].callMethod('getAppVersion'));
    });
  }
}
```

By the time this is added to the DOM, `devcieready` has already been fired, so the `app-version` event fires immediately.  Meanwhile, the `MyApp.created()` function has yet to run, and (apparently) none of the event listeners, including the above `"{{ onVersionInfo }}"` have been registered.  The `app-version` event fires, and no one hears it.  Some ms later, I get the message that `MyApp.created()` has run.  If I manually fire an `app-version` event now, it's properly handled.

I don't want to manually change all of the plugin files to use a Timer (setTimeout equiv) to make sure they fire after the MyApp constructor, but I don't know what else to do.  How can I make sure my event listeners register before the `deviceready` event triggers all my children elements to send their events?

Answer (score 0):

Code that accesses the DOM should not be run in the constructor of Polymer elements. The constructor should only be used to initialize local fields.

If you move the code a lifecycle callback like `attached()` or `ready()` it will work as expected.

See also https://github.com/dart-lang/polymer-dart/wiki/registration-and-lifecycle#lifecycle-callbacks

Comment: I've changed my code as you've suggested, and moved the functionality from ``CordovaAppVersion.created()`` to ``void ready()`` but the order of events is still not what I expect.  For the above elements, I have the following log statements (in order): ``cordovia-app-version created, cordovia-app-version ready, firing app-version event, myApp created, myApp ready``

Comment: To elaborate, the full chain of events is:  ``Polymer init complete, app-version created, app-version ready, firing app-version, app-version attached, myApp ready, myApp created, myApp attached``  This order of events seems very strange to me, even wrong, and I really don't know what to do about it.

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted the question. If the event fires too early you'll probably need to add the event listener outside polymer, for example in `main()`.